# Lines patterns - Adobe Illustrator CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a problem with creating a simple lines patterns. I need few patterns (see picture) which I can use repeatedly. Something like brushes in Photoshop. How can I do this? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a seamless pattern [tutorial](http://vector.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-tips/everything-you-ever-want-to-know-about-creating-seamless-patterns-in-illustrator/).

Comment: Welcome to GD! It's generally better to provide basic steps to something rather than an ambiguous link. Links  (and websites) can vanish.

Comment: true...will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a pattern brush.

Simply drag your single patterns above (assuming they are vector) to the Brush Panel in Illustrator. Choose "Pattern Brush" when asked. This will create a new pattern brush.

Then simply draw a path and click the brush in the Brush Panel.